# How to use DSP to speed-up a code on OMAP?

Tags: c++, c, embedded, signal-processing, omap

I'm working on a video codec for OMAP3430. I already have code written in C++, and I try to modify/port certain parts of it to take advantage of the DSP (the SDK (OMAP ZOOM3430 SDK) I have has an additional DSP).

I tried to port a small for loop which is running over a very small amount of data (~250 bytes), but about 2M times on different data. But the overload from the communication between CPU and DSP is much more than the gain (if I have any).

I assume this task is much like optimizing a code for the GPU's in normal computers. My question is porting what kind of parts would be beneficial? How do GPU programmers take care of such tasks?

### edit:

1. GPP application allocates a buffer of size 0x1000 bytes.
2. GPP application invokes DSPProcessor_ReserveMemory to reserve a DSP virtual address space for each allocated buffer using a size that is 4K greater than the allocated buffer to account for automatic page alignment. The total reservation size must also be aligned along a 4K page boundary.
3. GPP application invokes DSPProcessor_Map to map each allocated buffer to the DSP virtual address spaces reserved in the previous step.
4. GPP application prepares a message to notify the DSP execute phase of the base address of virtual address space, which have been mapped to a buffer allocated on the GPP. GPP application uses DSPNode_PutMessage to send the message to the DSP.
5. GPP invokes memcpy to copy the data to be processed into the shared memory.
6. GPP application invokes DSPProcessor_FlushMemory to ensure that the data cache has been flushed.
7. GPP application prepares a message to notify the DSP execute phase that it has finished writing to the buffer and the DSP may now access the buffer. The message also contains the amount of data written to the buffer so that the DSP will know just how much data to copy. The GPP uses DSPNode_PutMessage to send the message to the DSP and then invokes DSPNode_GetMessage to wait to hear a message back from the DSP.

After these the execution of DSP program starts, and DSP notifies the GPP with a message when it finishes the processing. Just to try I don't put any processing inside the DSP program. I just send a "processing finished" message back to the GPP. And this still consumes a lot of time. Could that be because of the internal/external memory usage, or is it merely because of the communication overload?

Comment: I've generally used the TI Code Composer tool chain when dealing with the C6xxx series so I won't be able to tell you specific Linux calls to use, but the C64xx hardware is roughly the same regardless.  When posible you want to avoid "handholding" for copying data.  I would expect the memcpy to tie up the processor in a copy loop, if possible find a DMA operation from the ARM to move the data.  Try and do whatever processing you can WHILE DMA operations are being performed in parallel.  Worse case you should be able to configure the C64xx to move data by programming the DMA registers directly.

Comment: Look at the documentation for the board, I can't find too much info on it because they are pushing the next generation of the Zoom kit, DMA operations will be able to transfer data at Buswidth*Clockspeed for syncronous busses.  If the processing you are doing does not require a nested loop, then it may take longer to move it over an external bus than doing the processing locally.  The external buses are typically 1/2 or 1/4 the core speed for parts in 400Mhz range.  If it's an async bus then it's even worse.

Comment: IF the bus speed is 100Mhz (to be conservative) and the word size is 32bits (C64xx can have a 64bit bus on the EMIF for standard parts. On OMAP IDK?) then (4096 bytes/4 bytes) / 100Mhz = 10.24us transfer time should be achivable for that amount of data using DMA.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the measurements I did, one messaging cycle between CPU and DSP takes about 160us. I don't know whether this is because of the kernel I use, or the bridge driver; but this is a very long time for a simple back & forth messaging.

It seems that it is only reasonable to port an algorithm to DSP if the total computational load is comparable to the time required for messaging; and if the algorithm is suitable for simultaneous computing on CPU and DSP.

Comment: Ignore the messaging. Just collect all the little DSP-jobs that you want to run in a shared memory buffer on the GPP side and once you've collected them all call the DSP once and let it do it's job. You could also move your entire video decoder to the DSP-side.

Answer (score 2):

The OMAP3430 does not have an on board DSP, it has a IVA2+ Video/Audio decode engine hooked to the system bus and the Cortex core has DSP-like SIMD instructions.  The GPU on the OMAP3430 is a PowerVR SGX based unit.  While it does have programmable shaders and i don't believe there is any support for general purpose programming ala CUDA or OpenCL.  I could be wrong but I've never heard of such support

If your using the IVA2+ encode/decode engine that is on board you need to use the proper libraries for this unit and it only supports specific codecs from that I know.  Are you trying to write your own library to this module?

If your using the Cortex's built in DSPish (SIMD instructions), post some code.

If your dev board has some extra DSP on it, what is the DSP and how is it connected to the OMAP?

As to the desktop GPU question, in the case of video decode you use the vender supplied function libraries to make calls to the hardware, there are several, VDAPU for Nvidia on linux, similar libraries on windows(PureViewHD I think its called).  ATI also has both linux and windows libraries for their on board decode engines, i don't know the names.

Comment: I've always heard that the OMAP3 has a C64+ DSP built in, in addition to the ARM Cortex A8.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments_OMAP#OMAP3

Comment: It depends on the particular model.  The ones used in the Beagle Board, and the Pandora Handheld have a C64xx, but many of the others do not.

Comment: I don't see a DPS anywhere on spec sheet as being part of the OMAP processor, interestingly the wiki entry doesn't mention the IVA2+ unit, this may be based on a TI DSP

http://focus.ti.com/general/docs/wtbu/wtbuproductcontent.tsp?contentId=14649&navigationId=12643&templateId=6123

Comment: The OMAP3530 has a 64xx built in. http://focus.ti.com/dsp/docs/dspcontent.tsp?contentId=53403
The part on his board doesn't have it built in, it's an external processor on the board.

Comment: Yes I use the LogicPD's ZOOM Board and it has a TMS32064x DSP.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the time base your transfering data in is, but I know the TMS32064x which is listed on the specsheet for the SDK has a very powerful DMA engine.  (I'm assuming it's the orignal ZOOM OMAP34X MDK. It says it has a 64xx.)  I would hope the OMAP has something simalar, use them to their fullest advantage.  I would recomend setting up "ping-pong" buffers in the interal ram of the 64xx and using the SDRAM as shared memory with the transfers handle by DMA.  External RAM is going to be a bottleneck on any of the 6xxx series parts so keep whatever you can locked into internal memory to improve performance.  Typically these parts will have the ability to bus 8 32bits words to the processor core once it's in internal memory, but that vary from part to part based on what level cache it allows you to map as direct access ram.  Cost sensitive parts from TI move the "mappable memory" farther away than some of the other chips.  Also all the manuals for the parts are available from TI for free download in PDF.  They even gave me hardcopies for free of the TMS320C6000 CPU and Instruction Set manual and many other books.

As far as programming is concerned you may need to use some of the "processor intrinsics" or inline assembly to optimize any math you are doing.  For the 64xx favor integer operation when possible because it doesn't have a built in floating point core.  (Those are in the 67xx series.)  If look at the excution units and you can map your calculations such that the different parts target different operations in a manner which can occur in a single cycle then you will be able to achive the best performance out of those parts.  The instruction set manual list the types of ops that are performed by each execution unit.  If you can break you calculation up in to a dual data flow sets and unwind the loops a bit the compiler will be "nicer" to you when full optimizaiton is on.  This is due to the fact that the processor is broken up into a left and a right side with nearly identical execution units on either side.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm using the external memory or internal. In the program (MPU) I call a malloc and then map this allocated memory to a shared memory with DSP. I followed a sample application written by TI. I'll put the details below.